# Comparing and merging a list of objects

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list containing many objects with this definition:

```
Public Class Helper
    Public Property UserPrincipal As UserPrincipal
    Public Property Groups As New List(Of String)
    Public Property Server As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Assume, one object looks like this:

```
UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
Groups = {group_1, group_2, group_3}
Server = {Server1}
```

And another one:

```
UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
Groups = {group_1, group_3}
Server = {Server2}
```

Now I want to check the property "Groups" of each object and create a new object if "Groups" of one object contains "Groups" of another object.

So the new list of objects should look like this:

```
UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
Groups = {group_1, group_2, group_3}
Server = {Server1, Server2}
```

Is this possible using linq?

Thanks and regards,
Jan

Update: 10:42: Changed type of 'Server'-property from string to list(of string)

Update 12:04: Let me try to clarify my question.
The task is to collect members of a local group of a server. To do this, I connect to each server using a new principalcontext with correct credentials, get the right group (it's the remote desktop users-group) and get all members of this group.
With this information, I fill the mentioned 'helper'-object containing the userprincipal (which is a member of the group), the group(s) (that are members of the remote desktop user-group) and the server-name.

So I got n * Helper-objects, where n is the server-count.

Now, there are two requirements: Let's say, I have two servers here, `server1` and `server2`. Everything equals but the servername differs, so I want only one object with property `Server = {server1, server2}`.

And the second requirement is basicly like the first one but: Do this also if the `Groups` property contains add least one unique correlation and add this group to the list, if it's not already in it.

Don't know if it's any clearer now :) Will show a short example now.

Object 1:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users}
    Server = {Server1}

Object 2:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users}
    Server = {Server2}

Expected object:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users}
    Server = {Server1, Server2}

Example 2:
Object 1:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users, Test-Users}
    Server = {Server1}

Object 2:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Test-Users}
    Server = {Server2}

Expected object:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users, Test-Users}
    Server = {Server1, Server2}

And last one, puhh:

Object 1:
    UserPrincpial.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Test-Users}
    Server = {Server1}

Object 2:
    UserPrincipal.Name = Jan
    Groups = {Domain-Users}
    Server = {Server1} or {Server2} etc. doesn't matter.

Expected result: No change cause properties `groups` are completely different.

Comment: You cannot change the type of the property `Server` from string to `List(Of string)`. So you either have to use a list in the first place or use a string and concat all with comma (or a different delimiter).

Comment: You can, you are simply not allowed to use Option Strict On. But note that this is not recommended

Comment: How is the `UserPrincipal` related, does the same group also have the same `UserPrincipal`? Or which of the group do you want to keep, the first?

Comment: The 'UserPrincipal' is not directly related to the groups, however it's usually a member of the group. But since I don't use a list of 'GroupPrincipal's here, it doesn't matter.

Comment: In your example data it appears that the `Groups` and `Server` properties are just unioned for each `UserPrincipal`. But your description sound like it is some sort of intersection. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Jan: i have asked because otherwise i can only take an arbitrary `UserPrincipal` of each group. Look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28296688/284240), especially the `x.group.First().UserPrincipal`. You haven't mentioned the rule, so i have used `First`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your updated question and your comments this seem to be what you want:

```
Dim upGroups = From helper In helpers 
               Group helper By helper.UserPrincipal Into Group
               Select New Helper With {
                 .UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal,
                 .Groups = Group.SelectMany(Function(h) h.Groups).Distinct().ToList(),
                 .Server = Group.SelectMany(Function(h) h.Server).Distinct().ToList()
               }
Dim newHelpers = upGroups.ToList()
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use `Groups.Intersect(h.Groups).Any()` to check which helpers contain intersecting groups. Then you can use a loop to merge them:

```
Dim query = From helper In helpers
            Let group = helpers.Where(Function(h) helper.Groups.Intersect(h.Groups).Any())

Dim processed As New HashSet(Of Helper)()
Dim newHelpers As New List(Of Helper)
For Each x In query
    If x.group.Any(AddressOf processed.Contains) Then
        ' was already processed, skip '
        Continue For
    End If
    Dim mergedHelper = New Helper With {
               .UserPrincipal = x.group.First().UserPrincipal,
               .Groups = x.group.SelectMany(Function(h) h.Groups).Distinct().ToList(),
               .Server = x.group.SelectMany(Function(h) h.Server).Distinct().ToList()
           }
    newHelpers.Add(mergedHelper)
    For Each helperInGroup In x.group
        processed.Add(helperInGroup)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: There seems to be an error somewhere. It spits out round about 5 entries only while my initial helperlist contains nearly 20.000) entries. :)

Comment: @Jan: so why is it incorrect? Your requirement was to merge all helpers which have intersecting groups, wasn't it? **Edit** Wait, i see that you have edited the question.

Comment: I'm getting a bit closer with your approach. I just don't use your processed hashset. However, now I'm getting the same resultset for each server not only one. With your code I'm getting only one userprincipal, not all.

Comment: @Jan: if you dont use the HashSet you will add the original helpers even if they were already merged with others.

Comment: That's right, but how do I get only the merged one's? If I'm using your code, all my userprincipals are gone :)

Comment: @Jan: no, they are not gone but only the first of each group is taken. That is what i have told you already earlier today if you look at my comments to your question. It's still not clear how you want to merge them. Also, i haven't still implemented your new requirement(your so called _first requirement_)) to also group by helpers with the same groups but different servers. Currenly i'm only grouping by helpers with intersecting grous no matter what servers they have.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to clarify it any further. Generally speaking, I need at least one object per userprincipal which may contain n groups and n servers. But if there is no match in groups a new object using the same userprincipal must be 'created'.

Comment: @Jan: so basically (in sql terms) you want to group by userprincipal. These groups should be merged into a single "record" where all Groups and all Servers are joined.

Comment: Yes, with the aforementioned restrictions.

Comment: @Jan: _what_ restriction, that you want a new object using the same userprincipal if there is no match in groups? I'm afraid that i don't understand what "create new" means. Do you want to create a duplicate or do you want to add this single userprincipal as it is?

Comment: The latter. The userprincipal is used only to get the name and the dn as I need this values in my export.

Comment: Hmm, now the servers are not grouped anymore, so I have an entry for each server.  Ok, giving up on that, maybe it's too hard for me to explain. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jan: but you don't have duplicate servers per userprincipal-group, have you? The `Distinct()` removes duplicates.

Comment: No, I don't. I've another idea, try playing a bit now. I will see if I could merge these objects while reading them from the server(s). This _might_ be easier and somewhat faster as I don't need to operate on such a large list afterwards.